# Can you measure While ($ie.Busy -eq $true)

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I couldn't find an exact answer to this when investigating this but was curious if it was possible to measure  `while ($ie.Busy -eq $true)` in as a time.

I have a script which is interacting with Internet Explorer and performing tasks, I thought it would be good from a data collection perspective to log loading times or similar.

Is this possible using  `while ($ie.Busy -eq $true)` or is there another way to measure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll want to capture is the `$startLoadTime` and `$endLoadTime` and get the difference between the two (`Start-Sleep` in the loop is optional but will prevent the Powershell process from using too much CPU):

```
$startLoadTime = [DateTime]::Now
while( $ie.Busy ){
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
}
$endLoadTime = [DateTime]::Now
$loadTimeElapsed = $endLoadTime - $startLoadTime
```

The returned `$loadTimeElapsed` variable is a [`System.TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8) object, which lets you easily see and process the elapsed time.

Note that while waiting for `$ie.Busy` to become `$false` you don't want to let the loop run unbound (will take up more CPU time than you'll want), which is why I threw the `Start-Sleep` in there. You can adjust the number of milliseconds for your needs if you need a resolution smaller than "within 200ms".

Comment: Hi Bender, thank you for this example and it works - I noticed, however, output generally matches the `Start-Sleep` - I noticed the section talking about increased CPU usage but the app i'm using isn't so intensive so believe it would be best to simply let it load and capture more acurate times - is this something that you believe would work and how exactly would you achieve this if not usnig `-seconds x` etc after `start-sleep`?

Comment: Ah I tested and realized I can simply put `{Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1}` and it'll output, after testing a few times, what appears to be accurate data - Thank you again Bender

Comment: Doing a test with a `while` loop, unchecked with nothing in the loop body it takes up 12% of my CPU time. With a 200ms sleep I see about 1-2% cpu time, if that. If you were doing actual processing in the loop expect to see those number much higher.